# How can I send notification from one user to another oneSignal & Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

I would like to send a notification from one user to another. Currently, most of the tutorials are outdated and a lot of methods are deprecated which worked in the past. I can send notifications from the server-side to users but not from user to user. I understand you need to use Token id and stuff but after countless hours I give up. Here, is what I have done so far and How do I set it up ?

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  static final String oneSignalAppId = "3******-9441-47c4-8f31-*********";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Chat App',
      
      home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
            if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
              return ChatScreen();
            }
            return AuthScreen();
          }),
    );
    //);
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    OneSignal.shared.setAppId(oneSignalAppId);
  }
}
```

The method to create user

```
void _submitAuthForm(
    String email,
    String userName,
    String password,
    File image, //will be null at login case but its okay
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx, //else you get an error in dialog of error
  ) async {
    UserCredential authResult; 
        authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            //create user
            email: email,
            password: password);
       
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(authResult.user.uid)
            .set({
          //save the new user username & email to collection 'users'
          'username': userName,
          'email': email,
          'image_url': url, //the link to the uploaded image
        });
      }
    }
```